# How to Create CycleTile Dynamically in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, live-tile

I would like to use the new Cycle Tile feature available in Windows Phone 8, although I am having trouble creating this dynamically. My issue arises when attempting to set the images for the Cycle Tile, I do not seem to be getting the correct paths for the images. What I have so far is as follows

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void CreateApplicationTile()
    {
        //App.PictureList.Pictures grabs all of my application images from IsolatedStorage
        int count = App.PictureList.Pictures.Count();
        int count1 = count - 9;
        var cycleImages = new List<Uri>();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            //I only want to add the 9 most recent images if available
            for (int i = count; i > count1; i--)
            {
                int index = i - 1;
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    //Set file to type CapturedPicture, which contains the jpg, name, date, etc.
                    var file = App.PictureList.Pictures[index] as CapturedPicture;
                    //TilePictureRepository class saves the file (picture) to "Shared/ShellContent/"
                    //TilePictureRepository.IsolatedStoragePath = "Shared/ShellContent/"
                    TilePictureRepository.Instance.SaveToLocalStorage(file, TilePictureRepository.IsolatedStoragePath);
                }
            }
        }


        // Select the application tile 
        ShellTile myTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

        if (myTile != null)
        {
            Uri[] u = new Uri[9];
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                IEnumerable<string> files = isf.GetFileNames(TilePictureRepository.IsolatedStoragePath + "*").Reverse();
                int x = 0;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    if (x < 9)
                    {
                        u[x] = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + file, UriKind.Absolute);
                        cycleImages.Add(u[x]);
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            }

            CycleTileData newTileData = new CycleTileData
            {
                Title = "Tile Test",
                SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Tile_Small_159x159.png", UriKind.Relative),
                CycleImages = cycleImages,
            };

            myTile.Update(newTileData);
        }
    }
```

From what I understand, tile images for the Cycle Tile should be saved in the ShellTile directory within IsolatedStorage. To do this, I am using the following class which I quickly modified (I really only am using the `SaveToLocalStorage` method)

TilePictureRepository.cs

```
#region Constants

    public const string IsolatedStoragePath = "Shared/ShellContent/";

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Picture> _pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        get { return _pictures; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Singleton Pattern

    private TilePictureRepository()
    {
        LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage();
    }

    public static readonly TilePictureRepository Instance = new TilePictureRepository();

    #endregion

    /// <summary>        
    /// Saves to local storage
    /// This method gets two parameters: the captured picture instance and the name of the pictures folder in the isolated storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capturedPicture"></param>
    /// <param name="directory"></param>
    public void SaveToLocalStorage(CapturedPicture capturedPicture, string directory)
    {
        //call IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to get an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists.
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(directory);

        //Combine the pictures folder and captured picture file name and use this path to create a new file 
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, capturedPicture.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.CreateFile(filePath))
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
            {
                capturedPicture.Serialize(writer);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all saved pictures and add them to the pictures list page
    /// </summary>
    public CapturedPicture LoadFromLocalStorage(string fileName, string directory)
    {
        //To open the file, add a call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Combine the directory and file name
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
        //use the path to open the picture file from the isolated storage by using the IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile method
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            //create a BinaryReader instance for deserializing the CapturedPicture instance
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                var capturedPicture = new CapturedPicture();
                //create a new instance of the type CapturedPicture called CapturedPicture.Deserialize to deserialize the captured picture and return it
                capturedPicture.Deserialize(reader);
                return capturedPicture;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all the pictures at start time
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage()
    {
        //add call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to open an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(IsolatedStoragePath);

        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames using the pictures directory and *.jpg as a filter to get all saved pictures
        var pictureFiles = isoFile.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(IsolatedStoragePath, "*.jpg"));            

        //Iterate through all the picture files in the list and load each using the LoadFromLocalStorage you created earlier
        foreach (var pictureFile in pictureFiles)
        {
            var picture = LoadFromLocalStorage(pictureFile, IsolatedStoragePath);
            _pictures.Add(picture);
        }
    }
```

My result is that as the smallest tile available on the start screen, I see the application tile, while the medium and large tile sizes only show a blank tile (just the accent color and application name).

Comment: There are a ton of places this could be breaking. You really need to run this through the debugger and come back with more information. Is it failing to move the pictures to the shell dir? Is it not able to get the current tile? Is it unable to find the pictures in the first place? There's just too much to debug without any type of real error to go on.

Comment: I am calling the `CreateApplicationTile` method when the application leaves the MainPage. `App.PictureList.Pictures` already contains images that have been loaded from IsolatedStorage, and copying the most recent 9 using `TilePictureRepository.Instance.SaveToLocalStorage` seems to work. `isf.GetFileNames` does retrieve the images, and I can see the `Uri`s matching `"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + file` within `cycleImages` after the loop completes. The tile is being retrieved, because setting the other tile properties works ok. I also do not see any errors while debugging.